# How to change URL from localhost to anther host at antd pro?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy, antd, ant-design-pro

I'm creating a **react antd-pro** app. 
How can I change the URL from localhost to my host name? 
Is this just changing the proxy config

```
chainWebpack: webpackPlugin,
     proxy: {
      '/server/api/': {
        target: 'https://preview.pro.ant.design/',
        changeOrigin: true,
       pathRewrite: { '^/server': '' },
      },
```

or should I do something else with jest?

```
module.exports = {
  testURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
  preset: 'jest-puppeteer',
  extraSetupFiles: ['./tests/setupTests.js'],
  globals: {
    ANT_DESIGN_PRO_ONLY_DO_NOT_USE_IN_YOUR_PRODUCTION: false,
    localStorage: null,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's for deployment, when I build and deployed my project, it took the domain url automatically.